# Sinon TypeError: Attempted to wrap undefined property getInternationals as function

Tags: javascript, testing, integration-testing, sinon, cypress

I'm using Cypress to write an integration test. Cypress uses Sinon for stubs and spies so cy.spy = sinon.spy.

I'm trying to spy on a method from an imported module.

I'm importing the module like so: `import * as internationals from "../../../src/api/Internationals";`

I then try to spy on a method inside `api/Internationals` like so: `cy.spy(internationals, "getInternationals");`

Resulting in this error:

> TypeError: Attempted to wrap undefined property getInternationals as function

Contents of `api/Internationals.js`:

```
import ApiClient from "./ApiClient";

export const getInternationals = ({ search, team, from, till, page = 1, per_page = 10, sort_column, sort_direction }) =>
  ApiClient.get(`/players`, {
    params: {
      search: search ? (search === "#" ? "hek" : search) : null,
      team: team ? team : null,
      from: from ? from : null,
      till: till ? till : null,
      page: page,
      per_page: per_page,
      sort_column: sort_column ? sort_column : null,
      sort_direction: sort_direction ? sort_direction : null
    }
  });
```

Test contents:

```
/// <reference types="Cypress" />

import * as internationals from "../../../src/api/Internationals";

describe("Can search for internationals", () => {
  it("Remembers filters after refreshing", () => {
    console.log(internationals);
    cy.spy(internationals, "getInternationals");

    expect(internationals.getInternationals).to.be.called;
  });
});
```

Console logging `internationals` shows:
[image]

Am I missing something?

Comment: what does `console.log(internationals)` print?

Comment: I've added a screenshot @glebbahmutov

Comment: it is weird that there is both `getInternationals` and a getter property `get getInternationals`

Comment: That's true, I have no idea why that is happening

Comment: `getInternationals` in console shows a tooltip 'Invoke property getter'. The `get getInternationals` reference seems to be the getter function itself, which you can access via `const getterFunction = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(internationals, "getInternationals").get;`.

Comment: I just noticed in your test, there's nothing to trigger the app's call to `getInternationals` between setting up the spy and `expect(...).to.be.called`. Is this the complete test, maybe you left out a `cy.visit()` or `.click()`? It might be useful to see the full picture, including how the app accesses getInternationals.

Answer (score 2):

Tracking through the error in the console, it's clear that Cypress is not handling the `export const getInternationals` construct correctly, but cannot tell why at a glance.

---

**NOTE: re-basing the import doesn't work, left for continuity of discussion**

You can dodge the problem by spying like this in your test

```js
const spyBase = {
  getInternationals: internationals.getInternationals
}
cy.spy(spyBase, "getInternationals");

expect(spyBase.getInternationals).to.be.called;
```

---

If you can alter the source code, add a default export to the module

```js
export const getInternationals = ...

export default {
  getInternationals
}
```

and import it like so

```js
import internationals from "../../../src/api/Internationals";
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I'm trying the first option, it no longer throws the original error so that's progress but now it says it is never called although I am sure it is because I can see the api call in the network tab. I've also tried moving the spy to before the call to visit but it doesn't make a difference :(

Comment: Sorry about that. It's sometimes difficult to fully mock up a problem scenario, so I skipped actually testing the call. Adding a spy to a function just adds a wrapper function, but obviously there needs to be a common base object that's imported in both the app and the spec.

Comment: This looks like a way forward [Sinon spies](https://sinonjs.org/releases/latest/spies/) - section 'Using a spy to wrap property getter and setter', but it seems Cypress checks don't account for getter properties (not sure if this is a Cypress problem or a Sinon problem).

Comment: Another thought - since `getInternationals` just calls `APIClient`, can you use `cy.spy(APIClient, "get")` instead?

Comment: The `export default ` option works like a charm with cypress, thanks a lot!